# Oracle in Instantclient_21_7 crashing upon test connection

Tags: oracle, odbc, driver, dsn, instantclient

I am having trouble setting up Oracle in Instantclient_21_7. I tried to add it as a user dsn and test connection, upon clicking test connection, it just crash, no error message or whatsoever. i enabled logging and it always shows as below.

odbcad32        2da8-b40    ENTER SQLAllocEnv
HENV *              0x000D9C94

odbcad32        2da8-b40    EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
HENV *              0x000D9C94 ( 0x03FBDEB8)

odbcad32        2da8-b40    ENTER SQLAllocConnect
HENV                0x03FBDEB8
HDBC *              0x000D9C98

odbcad32        2da8-b40    EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
HENV                0x03FBDEB8
HDBC *              0x000D9C98 ( 0x06A53198)

odbcad32        2da8-b40    ENTER SQLDriverConnectW
HDBC                0x06A53198
HWND                0x00120D9C
WCHAR *             0x58BB2430 [      -3] "******\ 0"
SWORD                       -3
WCHAR *             0x58BB2430
SWORD                       -3
SWORD *             0x00000000
UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>

Hope someone could help me, i been round and round on this issue for over a month now. I need to have it set-up as i will be using the driver to excel macro to execute query on oracle db.

Thank You.

Comment: On what platform  and version is this happening? What environment variables are used?

Comment: Also what driver manager and version?

Comment: hey guys i just had it resolved, it happened on 20_7 and 19_2, i ang using machine with AMD processor. It is compatibility issue with AMD, i had to downgrade to 18_5. 20_7,19_2 used to worked on my other machine with intel inside.